# How to convert normal JS array to JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

My current array is like

```
['service1', 'service2', 'service3']
```

and I need to convert it into like

```
[
  {'id':'1', 'serviceName':'service1'},
  {'id':'2', 'serviceName':'service2'},
  {'id':'2', 'serviceName':'service3'}
]
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Try this : const arr2=arr1.map(function(ele,index){return{'id':index+1,'servicename':ele};});console.log(arr2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let arr = ['service1', 'service2', 'service3'];
arr.map((item, index) => { return {id: index + 1, serviceName: item} });
```

Comment: Thanks, Tatul, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ['service1', 'service2', 'service3'];

console.log(arr.map((value, index) => {
    return {
        id: index + 1,
        serviceName: value
    };
}));
```

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will walk over each element and modify as per your requirement and then changes the string to object.